# mysql select sum anually for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple payments which have a date and a staff_id.
I want to get the sum of the payments for every staff_id for every year.

For example:

```
2011 - Staff1 - 66$
2011 - Staff2 - 24$
2012 - Staff1 - 86$
2012 - Staff2 - 0$
```

My idea was something like:

```
SELECT 
    staff_id, 
    YEAR(p.payment_date), 
    sum(p.amount) 
FROM 
    payment p 
WHERE 
    staff_id = (SELECT p.staff_id FROM payment p GROUP BY p.staff_id) 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(p.payment_date);
```

This will obviously not work because `(SELECT p.staff_id FROM payment p GROUP BY p.staff_id)` will return more than one value.

How can I do this right?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: a schema of the table would be very helpful here

Comment: ok, will do it in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group your sum by both the year and the staff id:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(p.payment_date), 
    staff_id, 
    sum(p.amount)
FROM 
    payment p 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(p.payment_date),
    staff_id
```

Comment: thx!
I srsly need to use my brain more often...